# I want to slide on hidden toolbar,but it's wrong

Tags: java, android

I want to slide on hidden toolbar but then I face an **error！**`（我想上滑隐藏toolbar，然后出错了。）`

```
android.view.InflateException:Binary XML file line #8: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout

Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
```

This is my layout code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/tuijian_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ToolBar_Title"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="测试标题"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"

                />

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

   <..recyclerview.../>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Thanks**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/id_toolbar_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

http://www.devexchanges.info/2016/06/material-design-tablayout-and-toolbar.html

I donot what is wrong i your code...Please refer this link 
I hope this may help you.

Comment: i treat ConstraintLayout as root layout, and my acvity extends AppCompatActivity ,then it worked!

Comment: ConstraintLayout >AppBarLayout>Toolbar

Answer (score 0):

Your Toolbar’s parent Layout is AppBarLayout. Therefore, you can’t use constraints in your Toolbar. So remove the constraints.
Your toolbar should look like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/tuijian_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">
```

Note: if you want to set a title you don’t have to use TextView. You can use title attribute inside a toolbar. Or setting it programmatically as in “setTitle();” inside activity